# Accessing properties of a property while using get set accessors

Tags: c#, accessor

This may seem like a strange question, but here I go anyway.

I have a class called Sprite that has properties such as "Position" and "Size". When one of these properties are changed I need to fire a private method that changes the rectangle with the new position/size that is used in the Draw() method.

So I thought I would use get set accessors so on the set I could set the private position varaible and then fire the event. Like this:

```
private Vector3 position;
public Vector3 Position { 
    get { return this.position; } 
    set {
        this.position = value;
        this.SetDrawRectangle();
    }
}
```

This works fine until I want to use one of Position's properties such as X, Y or Z. So if I was to do:

```
sprite.Position.X = 10;
```

It won't work, the error I get is

> Error  1   Cannot modify the return value of '.Sprite.Position' because it is not a variable.

I would have to do this:

```
sprite.Position = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
```

But this would be awkward in some situations because you would have to keep passing the current Y and Z floats back in to the new Vector3.

Has anyone got some help for a situation like this, or is what I'm trying to do just wrong and not possible.

Thanks in advance and I apologize for my ignorance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute this code

```
sprite.Position.X = 10;
```

`Sprite.Position`'s setter will not be called. It just calls the getter for `Sprite.Position` and then the setter for `Vector.X` which fails because `Vector.X` seems read-only.

So the answer is Yes if you can modify the code for `Vector` class and No if you can't unless you want to use Reflection.

Comment: I see! That makes some sense and at-least explains to me why it doesn't work. Can you think of a way around it then so I can read Vector.X. This would obviously still be a problem if this was a "Point" or "Rectangle" or something, does it just mean that you can't use accessors on properties that have properties inside them?

Comment: Note that the set accessor will not be called because YOU didn't called it in your assignment. You just `get` the `Position` property and try to `set` the `X`. There is no `set` invoked on `Sprite.Position` :)

Comment: I will explain more if it's still not clear. This is so much important

Comment: Compare that to `sprite.Position = new Vector(10, sprite.Position.Y, sprite.Position.Z);` which actually creates a new `Vector` object and calls `Sprite.Position.set`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Vector3.Set](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Set.html) method.

```
Position.Set(10, 0, 0);
```

Comment: But in this case I still wouldn't be able to JUST modify the X, Y or Z properties? Like "sprite.Position.Y = 50;"